# Robocopy DCOPY:DAT invalid paramter?

Tags: windows, robocopy

I want to clone an sd card, trying to use `robocopy`. What's wrong with the following statement?

```
ROBOCOPY e:\ c:\backup /MIR /COPYALL /DCOPY:DAT
```

Output: `Invalid Paramter #5 : "/DCOPY:DAT"`

What works would be a `/DCOPY:T`. But why can't I use the `:DAT` options?

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: Windows 7 most recent

Comment: What file system on the SD card?

Comment: What does 'robocopy /?' produce for DCOPY? I am seeing some older references online that only describe a valid flag of 'T' for DCOPY.

Comment: the filesystem is `exFat`.

Comment: @DanielK you're right, the help menu only outputs the `T` flag for `DCOPY`. I true, how could I then achieve the same result that `DCOPY:DAT` would produce? Or is that already included in `COPYALL`? Unfortunately there are so many references that just state the dcopy:dat paramter...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Knowledge base article 2646535](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2646535/significantly-slower-directory-tree-replication-performance-when-you-u?wa=wsignin1.0) addresses this in passing:

> The default Robocopy behavior in Windows 7 and in Windows Server 2008 R2 (in the released versions and the hotfixed versions) is the same as using the /DCOPY:DA option.

So `/DCOPY:T` on Windows 7 is equivalent to `/DCOPY:DAT` on Windows 10.  The Windows 7 version simply doesn't give you the option to *not* copy extended attributes and alternate data streams.

Note that the KB article linked above describes a hotfix that gives Windows 7 the new command line options, but I recommend against using it unless you have a compelling need.